# How to overwrite or delete a line in file using python

Tags: python, file

I am getting stream of data from an iterator and I would like to dump that to a file. I am doing that as below for now

```
data_stream = range(100)    # for simplicity

with open('mydump', 'wb') as fh:
    for new_line in data_stream:
        new_line_data = str(new_line)+'\n'
        fh.write(new_line_data.encode())
```

Here I need a functionality to go back and delete some lines based on a condition.

```
with open('mydump', 'wb') as fh:
    for new_line in data_stream:
        new_line_data = str(new_line)+'\n'
        fh.write(new_line_data.encode())
        if 'delete' in new_line:
            fh.seek(0)
            fh.delete() # how to delete first line (or nth line)
```

Comment: You can't. Loop over lines, copy the ones you want to another file. Don't copy the lines you don't want.

Comment: It is also possible to do that within the original file: seek to the section after what is to be deleted, read it out & write it back starting where the deleted section starts.  (Or just overwrite your file w/ @alani's result.) Even better: don't write them out in the first place (if possible).

Comment: @ScottHunter Yes, at a stretch you could do this, but then have to keep seeking back and forth between two offsets (for reading and writing) as you loop over lines, or have two filehandles open on the same file. (And in either case, remember to truncate when you have finished writing.) Just about possible but very messy.

Comment: Problem is I am working with streams and I cant decide what to write and what not to write. So I am thinking to go back and delete/overwrite a specific line with empty spaces

Comment: Delete is not the same as overwrite; the latter is much easier but wasteful (of space).

Comment: @newbie Unless you don't have space on the filesystem to write a temporary output file, just copy the lines of interest to a separate output file and then afterwards you can rename it back on top of the input file.